# Wrong output result from VBA code in Access tool

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am having some issue with a value that is being determined from some VBA code in my Access tool. I am quite a beginner with VBA and this code was developed alongside a very experienced VBA programmer (who has gone away hence is unable to assist me).

This is the code in question:

```
Private Sub ValidatePrinting()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, PrintMethodVal As Boolean, PracIdVal As Long, datePrintedcol As String, PrintedCount As Integer, ImportedCount As Integer
Dim fromtxt As String, wheretxt As String, conditionalImportedCount As Integer, PrintConditions As Boolean
PrintMethodVal = Me.filter_PrintMethod.Value
PracIdVal = Me.filter_PracticeID.Value
datePrintedcol = Me.filter_LetterRound.Value
datePrintedcol = IIf(datePrintedcol = "1st Round", "datePrinted_1st", IIf(datePrintedcol = "2nd Round", "datePrinted_2nd", ""))
PrintedCount = Me.filter_LetterCount.Value
PrintConditions = Me.filter_PrintConditions.Value
If (datePrintedcol = "") Then
    Call DisplayMessage("All letters already sent")
Else
    fromtxt = " tbl_main_ListLog as T INNER JOIN tbl_dbextract_GPPractice as GPP ON T.GPPracticeID = GPP.Id"
    wheretxt = PrintSQLCriteria(PracIdVal, datePrintedcol)
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(PrintValidationSQL(PrintMethodVal, fromtxt, wheretxt))
    ImportedCount = rst.Fields(0).Value
    conditionalImportedCount = rst.Fields(1).Value
    If ImportedCount = conditionalImportedCount Then
        If ImportedCount = PrintedCount Then
            If PrintMethodVal = PrintConditions Then
                tb_Result = "All OK"
                CurrentDb.Execute (" update " & fromtxt & " set " & datePrintedcol & " = date() " & wheretxt)
            Else
                tb_Result = "Wrong print method selected"
            End If
        Else
            tb_Result = "Counts don't match"
        End If
    Else
        tb_Result = "Mismatched print conditions"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

So the issue is, when the `PrintMethodVal` does not equal `PrintConditions` it outputs "Mismatched Print conditions" as opposed to the "Wrong print method selected" which is what it should. It also outputs "Mismatched Print conditions" when the `ImportedCount` also does not equal the `PrintedCount` (as well as the first situation), which is weird as the If should end there and output "Counts don't match".

This code was functioning correctly when originally developed, but I had to include the check for `PrintMethodVal = PrintConditions`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is showing "Mismatched Print conditions" because `ImportedCount` isn't the same value as `conditionalImportedCount`.  Did you happen to change the query to return different fields as the first and second fields in the query?

Comment: No I didn't modify the query at all. When `PrintMethodVal` = `PrintConditions`, the rest of the code runs fine, and the correct messages display. So in the ones I've tested, `ImportedCount` is equal to `conditionalImportdCount`.

Comment: Try testing one that doesn't work, but place a breakpoint on the line saying `If ImportedCount = conditionalImportedCount Then` and, when it stops, have a look to see what the values of `ImportedCount` and `conditionalImportedCount` are.

Comment: you are looking in the wrong place .... `ImportedCount = conditionalImportedCount` is false, so the two are not equal   .... it probably never gets to this line `If ImportedCount = PrintedCount Then`

Comment: Okay so I used a break point and you are both correct. But I don't understand why when I change the `PrintConditions` value - which is boolean - it is impacting the `conditionalImportedCount`.

Comment: You are using a couple of functions (`PrintValidationSQL(PrintMethodVal, fromtxt, wheretxt)` and `PrintSQLCriteria(PracIdVal, datePrintedcol)`) which we don't have the code for - do either of those return different values based on something to do with `PrintConditions`.  It may actually help if you compare the output from `PrintValidationSQL(PrintMethodVal, fromtxt, wheretxt)` for a case where it does what you expect with the output for a case where it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue - `PrintMethodVal` was being used in the query to determine the statement `ImportedCount = conditionalImportedCount`, so when the value of `PrintMethodVal` was changed by the user that all occured. 
I just moved the `If PrintMethodVal = PrintConditions` to before the `ImportedCount = conditionalImportedCount`.

Comment: Another satisfied customer :)